# I am having hard time writing a HiveQL Join

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql

I am pretty sure this question have been asked but can't get my search query to return the answer. I have two table

```
**Table Online**
Col1   Col2    Score   |
a      b       1       |
a      c       2       |
a      d       3       |
f      e       4       |

**Table Offline**
Col1   Col2    Score   |
a      m       10      |
a      c       20      |
a      d       30      |
t      k       40      |


**Table Output**
Col1  Col2  Online.Score  Offline.Score    |
a     c     2             20               |    
a     d     3             30               |
a     b     1                              |
a     m                   10               |
```

Comment: And where are `f e` and `t k` rows? They are filetered in output? Please explain the logic

Comment: you need to specify what logic you want to apply on these two input tables to generate the output you desire.  Without that it's difficult for people to provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(onl.col1, ofl.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(onl.col2, ofl.col2) as col2,
       onl.score, ofl.score
from (select onl.*
      from online onl
      where onl.col1 = 'a'
     ) onl full join
     (select ofl.*
      from offline ofl
      where ofl.col1 = 'a'
     ) ofl
     on onl.col1 = ofl.col1 and onl.col2 = ofl.col2;
```

Filtering is tricky withe `full join`, which is why this uses a subquery.

Comment: this looks much better

Comment: can this be more generic, a is just an example it could be any value .... sorry for misleading example

Comment: @NomanShaukat . . . I don't know what your comment is trying to say.  What do you mean "any value"?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query!

```
SELECT online.col1
    ,online.col2
    ,coalesce(online.score, 0) AS onlinescore
    ,coalesce(offlilne.score, 0) AS offlinescore
FROM online
INNER JOIN offline
    ON online.col1 = offline.col1
    AND online.col2 = offline.col2
UNION ALL
SELECT online.col1
    ,online.col2
    ,coalesce(online.score, 0) AS onlinescore
    ,'' AS offlinescore
FROM online
LEFT JOIN offline
    ON online.col1 = offline.col1
    AND online.col2 = offline.col2
WHERE offline.col1 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT offline.col1
    ,offline.col2
    ,'' AS onlinescore
    ,coalesce(offline.score, 0) AS offlinescore
FROM offline
LEFT JOIN online
    ON online.col1 = offline.col1
    AND online.col2 = offline.col2
WHERE online.col1 IS NULL
```